# Flask-User with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine, flask-user

I'm trying to follow the Flask-User documentation with MongoDB.

However, when I try to connect to my MongoDB Atlas, it's always writing to a "test" database, instead of the one I specify.

I have identified that it is because of the Flask-MongoEngine that is being used, as it mentions that

> By default, Flask-MongoEngine assumes that the mongod instance is
>   running on localhost on port 27017, and you wish to connect to the
>   database named test.

However, even after inputting my URI details, I still keep writing to the test database.

> Uri style connections are also supported, just supply the uri as the
>   hostin the ‘MONGODB_SETTINGS’ dictionary with app.config. Note that
>   database name from uri has priority over name.

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = { 'db': 'project1', 'host': 'mongodb://localhost/database_name' } 
My code
```

My configuration settings (albeit in another syntax) are as below

```
app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = '<redcated-database-name>'
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'mongodb+srv://<redcated-user>:<redcated-pw>@gapcluster-np4bu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = 27017
app.config["MONGODB_CONNECTION"] = False
```

Has anyone successfully used Flask-User with MongoDB Atlas before?

Comment: Your MONGODB_HOST specifies the `test` database. See `/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. The `test` string there is your database name.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my query.

I find it strange for the prompter that they gave below, it wasn't brought up that I would have to replace <test> with the name of the database you want to write to.

https://i.imgur.com/v0XOY6g.png

Please submit it as an answer, and I'll be able to mark it as the solution!